# How to use a function to determine the initial state using class components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use a function that returns a number which would be used as the initial state for `numOfNewNotifications`. Below is my code and my error:

```
class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      wasViewed: false,
      numOfNewNotifications: findNumOfNewNotifications(this.props.conversation.messages)
    }
  }  

  findNumOfNewNotifications = (messages) => {
    if (!this.state.wasviewed) {
      let counter = 0
      for (let msg of messages) {
        if (!msg.wasViwed) {
          counter++
        }
      }
      return counter
    }
  }
```

Error

```
Failed to compile
src\components\Sidebar\Chat.js
  Line 29:30:  'findNumOfNewNotifications' is not defined  no-undef
```

I know this is a crummy code, but I have only used hooks, so class components are foreign to me. Any help is appreciated.

Also, I know props is correctly passed into the component. Thanks

Comment: Can you do that with Class Components? I am receiving an unexpected token error at that spot.

Comment: @oh it should be `numOfNewNotifications: this.findNumOfNewNotifications(this.props.conversation.messages)`

Comment: Good catch! Getting a new error now and diving into that

Comment: `this.state` won't be defined yet in the constructor, so it can't be referenced in the `findNumOfNewNotifications` utility in the constructor. What is the new error you are digging into? Please update your question with the most recent relevant details and code.